# Failed to Connect to Azure Public IP/Load Balancer (Connection Refused)

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-cloud-services, azure-virtual-network, network-security-groups

I'm trying to set up a basic Azure load-balanced cluster of VMs, but am having issues accessing them outside of the virtual network that Azure creates.  A sample request that I am testing with:

`curl http://<publicIP of load balancer>:8080/rio/health`

returns "Failed to connect; connection refused"

Notably:
I can call from box 0 to box 1 using the private IP addresses.  I can call from box 0 to 1 using the public IP address.  I **can not** call from an external source to box 1 or the load balancer using the public IP.

So what I'm asking is, what else could be preventing me from accessing the virtual network in Azure externally?  I have created both Inbound and Outbound Security rules from the Azure portal to allow any protocol from source port * to destination port *.  Also, I created a load balancing rule to forward from port 8080 to backend port 8080.  Anything else I'm missing to make the public IP accessible externally?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't tell you what the exact problem is, but this really smells like a Network Security Group (NSG) config problem. It works within the VNET because there's a default rule on NSGs to allow all traffic originating in the VNET.  You can see the default rules defined here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-nsg/.  Do you have the NSG associated with the VMs' NICs?

Comment: Yeah, I did have a NSG associated with it - see answer below.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The issue I ran into here was I needed not only a load balancing rule to forward port 80 to 8080, but to add a probe on port 8080 as well!